# Drools 6 EventFactHandle StackOverflowError

Tags: java, drools, drools-fusion

I have a WEB application that is constantly firing all rules and after several minutes of running (even days), I got java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.drools.core.common.EventFactHandle.increaseActivationsCount(EventFactHandle.java:170).
I saw that part of code and looks like that there is a recursive method calling, but I am not sure why is happening this or event worst, how to avoid it.
The drools version I am using is 6.3.0 Final

Comment: I think you will need to provide a bit more specific information, I doubt that anyone can help you with this little information. What do your rules look like etc?

Comment: I have so many rules that are being executed and one thread that runs "fireAllRules" every 30seconds, until it dies for the StackOverflowError. Please, tell me what information could be useful.

Comment: Looking at EventFactHandle code, I am seeing several places that could throw this recursive exception, like:
* public long getActivationsCount()
* public void increaseActivationsCount()
* public void decreaseActivationsCount()